# Android SDK manager 4.1.1 package not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I need to test my Android app on a device running jelly bean 4.1.1, however in the SDK manager there is no 4.1.1 package available for download. The closest options are 4.1.2 and 4.0.3, choosing either of these results in my device not being detected.

Is there something I'm missing? Shouldn't 4.1.1 be available in the SDK manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The closest options are 4.1.2 and 4.0.3, choosing either of these results in my device not being detected.

I do not see 4.1.2 in the SDK Manager. I see Android 4.1, which is as it should be.

(though I do see some updates to that API level in the SDK that I will need to download when I am not on a conference WiFi network...)

> Is there something I'm missing?

No.

> Shouldn't 4.1.1 be available in the SDK manager?

No. The SDK Manager goes by API levels, not consumer-facing patch releases. Android 4.1 defined API Level 16, and neither 4.1.1 nor 4.1.2 created a new API level. From the standpoint of a developer, 4.1 and 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 should behave identically. If they don't, that's a bug.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the information. The only problem I had was that I overlooked setting "USB debugging" on my device, now that this is enabled I can choose this device for any compatible packages.